# png image doesn't show in wordPAd but shows in Word2010

Tags: png, richtextbox, rtf

I have the following rtf file:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang4105{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Arial;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue255;}
\uc1\pard\cf1\i\f0\fs22 {\*\shppict{\pict\pngblip\pichgoal1020\picwgoal1200
89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d494844520000005000000044080200000099342577000000017352474200aece1ce90000000467414d410000b18f0bfc
6105000000097048597300000ec300000ec301c76fa8640000033449444154785eed9a4b8edc300c44fb12d96599c3e60a395aae102067e8105d6582
2e49b4d4767b6cc70f8581cc9f58fd19cc621ecfff8cdbf0d5b90d5f829f8f6f109f036b0dfbe8638a5b06860dcbc4838b4b076ec34bc84488b93370
cd5f5a09b7e1cff3f7fb0f1113bbb0b7e1aabd3d3d9fd5b0b5b818ea631bc39db72665a3ab7bf15097b193e14e3f9d35b1aca725b29f619e527acaa4
e60b0cbfb165425e59666fc30bbc63d8eec8c5ba8932929014575343c38d61c33d7e2c12c568c1afdf7faa62baa03a2a995f65c0706bfbfc4a74b918
6dbb35b1624eec8db4e22d7a0d27738752888843112a85d62dc9ed55de372c5b1e565c7762c0b00c3a976823372c3da7162d550d4b694b28cebf42e5
e7c2e3dee807a9846281d08a3b3207cc0cc78a522c9a93df5a6db716c81fed67ac8c6acd6fc51d99c3280c4b2e0a45c6d0c532c4c4c4546f3ffdf00a
eb4be3e7ea7ca31537bcd7c5c48b87e42026e754ef2883320a626eaab79f7e7885eb5da672be510d1ad20b3137a186196ee08b3af228d3cacd10c19c
98954617d38172a6215d10737368984f1dc87dc9d208c6023fdb01c2a321bd2ea603b10b488b89891a031f6920f7f9636b42acf7b31d20e92a857a27
4e33a4d8c4449bbae1a309bb46b75260626289231ab6b52462825b09422f23bdd4ffd292899f13ef2b90b2446ce826fbd3b2ca269f2b43be8d119f66
357e16b1749c370dcbf526643b49dc1a32b925560f326cd8285f7826bae9797b3bc5b66ede312c57e66f579521c3568c7a8947a1b787b5861119f29c
17c7e1c97c293331b1c42ac37c7ee1ef43026af2b238dc2bcb1644bcd8856cc2da775856b1c744490d522552e662fa45dc0762a2c6aedfe172572749
198b57c84a10737336306c6222657169237939784a91ad20e626de310c64eee24e3b1806b218c4dc1ac3860c85982bd8cd3090ad4c88af326cc85017
d3139d1b6f6818945bad35ecc86897eddaef7673c386ecb3996120d345b09488530a92540f71878d0d3bf18e9658dac14ac3865ffa29c38edfb42836
ccc9dff92170cbc70d1bbeb17beb516cdc0a1b3b6658fea7f4148a2f629761e93f9d6ec34b483fa3a7658f5f5a87e2367c756ec357e7367c756ec357
e7367c6d9ecf7fb9245ee11e01346e0000000049454e44ae426082
}}

}
```

If I open it with MS Word, the picture shows. If I open it in WordPad, the picture doesn't show (looks like an empty document. Any idea?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Word supports more image formats in its RTF format than Wordpad. Wordpad only supports BMP from what I know but MS Word will support PNG, JPEG and BMP. It looks like the image in your sample is stored as a PNG.

If you want your image to be viewable in both applications you should insert the image using Wordpad and then you will be able to view it in MS Word.

If you're using a converter to generate your RTF (like SautinSoft) then there should be an option in there to make your images Word or Wordpad compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a JPG that did only appear in the RTF control under some - unclear - circumstances (which is, as wild guess guess, a reference DC in the RTF control, or the visibility, or ... well unclear as I said). It did not show in WordPad, but in our application if the RTF control was visible, but not if the RTF control was invisible and just used to paint the RTF text.

Embedding a BMP instead of the JPG did work in all cases.